# Abend Causing Line

Tags: db2, cobol, mainframe, cics, rexx

Is there any way that we can find the exact line number that causes an abend ( like SO4C) from the Offset(like `offset +00007D0A at address 1515CD0A`) given in the spool with the error message.?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your program is compiled with options OFFSET,NOLIST, you will have a list of verbs/line numbers in the output listing which contain the "offset" from the start of the program. The line number on the the listing which has the closest offset, but less than or equal to, the "offset" reported in the abend, is where you want to look.

If you use NOOFFSET,LIST, you will get the "generated assembler" in your compile listing, and your abend "offset" should match exactly to the "offset" of one of the generated instructions, and you should be able to easily identify the COBOL source line from that, it is the first verb with line number before the actual machine instruction listed.

Bear in mind that in the rare cases in which you've managed to overwrite program code and that has eventually caused an abend you'll have to work harder, but for an "ordinary" abend it is quite straightforward.

If you use compiler options NOLIST,NOOFFSET, then you will have no clue. Re-run the compile with one of the options set. Unless the program sizes are *identical*, run the abending job again as well

If you use LIST,OFFSET, the compiler will produce a diagnostic message, and you will have to choose one of the valid options. LIST and OFFSET are mutually exclusive.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that some abends, like S04C, are generated by (in this case) DB2 routines that are called by DSNHLI, so the offset may not make sense, e.g., be way beyond the size of your program object. However, CEEDUMP will show you the point of the last call in the stack (again, for S04C, DSNHLI or similar), and you can use this to determine where the call that generated the error is.

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr, I don't see how your point relates to the question. Although the tags provided are confusing (DB2, CICS, REXX) there is nothing to indicate it is other than a plain abend in a COBOL program just doing some COBOL stuff at the time. For any address/offset which is outside a COBOL program, there is obviously a different process involved in working out how program control "got there". Perhaps I missed it, but I didn't see anything in the question which would require mention of hundreds of remote possibilities.

Comment: Bill, the fact he mentioned S04C points to DB2 and by definition would be outside the compiler-generated code from the COBOL source. Your classic S0Cx abends would probably be in the compiled code, and the offset calculation would be in the program.

Comment: The answer was accepted within not many minutes of my posting it, so I assumed it is not a case where the abend is in another module, which hasn't been identified, and which is located "after" the COBOL program and therefore is thought by the abend-reporter erroneously to be part of the COBOL program, It does not say S04C, it says SO4C. Tagged db2, but also cics, rexx. Without the Accept, it would more likely be S04C. With the Accept, I think S0C4. Let's ask Basil... actually, he's not been on line since an hour after asking the question, so I guess we'll never know...