# Data validation for file and formatting the output

Tags: cobol, mainframe

I'm trying to code a program to determine if different kinds of errors appear in a given file. I'm going to post my entire code, because I honestly have no idea where I'm going wrong here. It's just abending on me. The data validation is 2100-error-checking.

```
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. ASSIGNMENT1.
   AUTHOR.  AARON.

  ******************************************************************
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
  *  defines the external files - an input file and output file
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.


       SELECT DATVAL02 ASSIGN TO DATAIN
          FILE STATUS IS EF-STATUS.

       SELECT REPORT-FILE ASSIGN TO DATAOUT
          FILE STATUS IS PF-STATUS.

   DATA DIVISION.

   FILE SECTION.
   FD DATVAL02.
   01 SALES-RECORD.
       05 RECORD-CODE   PIC XX.
       05 FILLER        PIC X.
       05 VEND-NUM      PIC X(8).
       05 DATE-DUE.
            05 YEAR-DUE      PIC XX.
            05 MONTH-DUE     PIC XX.
            05 DAY-DUE       PIC XX.
       05 VEND-NAME     PIC X(20).
       05 FILLER        PIC XXX.
       05 AMT-DUE       PIC S9(6)V99.


   FD REPORT-FILE.
   01 REPORT-RECORD                PIC X(80).

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

   01 FLAGS-AND-ACCUMLATORS.
       05 VALID-RECORDS     PIC S99 VALUE 0.
       05 INVALID-RECORDS   PIC S99 VALUE 0.
       05 EF-STATUS       PIC 99  VALUE 0.
       05 PF-STATUS       PIC 99  VALUE 0.
       05 A-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 C-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 E-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 F-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 B-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 D-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 G-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 H-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 I-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 A-AST             PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 BC-AST            PIC X(8) VALUE SPACES.
       05 D-AST             PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 E-AST             PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 F-AST             PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 G-AST             PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.
       05 H-AST             PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.
       05 I-AST             PIC X(8) VALUE SPACES.
       05 END-OF-FILE      PIC XXX VALUE "NO".
       05 ERROR-FLAG        PIC XXX VALUE SPACES.
       05 ERROR-FLAG2       PIC XXX VALUE SPACES.
       05 ERROR-FILLER      PIC XXX VALUE SPACES.
       05 VC                PIC XX VALUE "VC".
       05 NOO               PIC XX VALUE "NO".
       05 D-CHECK           PIC S9999999V99.
       05 DAY-DUE-NUM       PIC 99.
       05 MONTH-DUE-NUM     PIC 99.


   01 HEADING-LINE-1.
       05           PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.
       05           PIC X(24) VALUE
            "VENDOR RECORD VALIDATION".
       05           PIC X(24) VALUE SPACES.
       05           PIC X(6)  VALUE
            "PAGE 1".

   01 HEADING-LINE-2.
       05           PIC XX VALUE
            "RC".
       05           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05           PIC X(8) VALUE
            "VENDOR #".
       05           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05           PIC X(8) VALUE
            "DATE DUE".
       05           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05           PIC X(11) VALUE
            "VENDOR NAME".
       05           PIC X(6) VALUE SPACES.
       05           PIC X(10) VALUE
            "AMOUNT DUE".
       05           PIC XXX VALUE SPACES.
       05           PIC X(16) VALUE
            "-- ERROR CODES--".

    01 DETAIL-LINE.
       05 RECORD-CODE-OUT           PIC XX.
       05                           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 VEND-NUM-OUT              PIC X(8).
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 YEAR-DUE-OUT              PIC XX.
       05 MONTH-DUE-OUT             PIC XX.
       05 DAY-DUE-OUT               PIC XX.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 VEND-NAME-OUT             PIC X(20).
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 AMT-DUE-OUT               PIC 999,999.99.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 A-ERROR-OUT               PIC X VALUE SPACES.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 B-ERROR-OUT               PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 C-ERROR-OUT               PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 D-ERROR-OUT               PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 E-ERROR-OUT               PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 F-ERROR-OUT               PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 G-ERROR-OUT               PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 H-ERROR-OUT               PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 I-ERROR-OUT               PIC X VALUE SPACE.

   01 ASTERISK-LINE.
       05 A-AST-OUT                 PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05                           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 BC-AST-OUT                PIC X(8) VALUE SPACES.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 D-AST-OUT                 PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05                           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 E-AST-OUT                 PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05                           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 F-AST-OUT                 PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 G-AST-OUT                 PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 I-AST-OUT                 PIC X(8) VALUE SPACES.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 H-AST-OUT                 PIC X(8) VALUE SPACES.


   01 RECORD-TOTALS.
       05                           PIC X(16) VALUE
            "VALID RECORDS: ".
       05 VALID-RECORDS-OUT         PIC 99.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05                           PIC X(17) VALUE
            "INVALID RECORDS: ".
       05 INVALID-RECORDS-OUT       PIC 99.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.

   1000-MAIN-CONTROL.
       PERFORM 2000-INITIALIZE.
       PERFORM UNTIL END-OF-FILE = "YES"
         READ DATVAL02
           AT END
             MOVE "YES" TO END-OF-FILE
           NOT AT END
             PERFORM 2100-ERROR-ROUTINE
             IF ERROR-FLAG = "YES"
                PERFORM 2500-PROCESS
                PERFORM 3000-PROCESS
                PERFORM 4200-REINITILIZE
             END-IF
             IF ERROR-FLAG = "NO"
                PERFORM 2500-PROCESS
             END-IF
         END-READ
       END-PERFORM.
       PERFORM 4000-PROCESS.
       PERFORM 4500-TERMINATE.
       STOP RUN.

   2000-INITIALIZE.
       OPEN INPUT DATVAL02.
       OPEN OUTPUT REPORT-FILE.

       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM HEADING-LINE-1.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM HEADING-LINE-2.

   2100-ERROR-ROUTINE.
       MOVE "NO"                   TO ERROR-FLAG.
       MOVE "NO"                   TO ERROR-FLAG2.

       IF VEND-NUM = SPACES
           MOVE "YES"              TO ERROR-FLAG
           MOVE "********"         TO BC-AST-OUT
           MOVE "B"               TO B-ERROR-OUT
       END-IF.

       IF VEND-NUM IS NOT NUMERIC AND ERROR-FLAG = NOO
           MOVE "YES"              TO ERROR-FLAG
           MOVE "********"        TO BC-AST-OUT
           MOVE "C"                TO C-ERROR-OUT
       END-IF.

       IF RECORD-CODE IS NOT = VC
           MOVE "YES"              TO ERROR-FLAG
           MOVE "**"               TO A-AST-OUT
           MOVE "A"                TO A-ERROR-OUT
       END-IF.

       IF DATE-DUE IS NOT NUMERIC
           MOVE "YES"              TO ERROR-FLAG2
           MOVE "YES"              TO ERROR-FLAG
           MOVE "**"               TO D-AST-OUT
           MOVE "D"               TO D-ERROR-OUT
           MOVE "**"              TO E-AST-OUT
           MOVE "**"              TO F-AST-OUT
       END-IF.

       IF DATE-DUE = 0 AND ERROR-FLAG2 = NOO
          IF AMT-DUE IS > 0
              MOVE "YES"           TO ERROR-FLAG
              MOVE "YES"           TO ERROR-FLAG2
              MOVE "**"           TO D-AST-OUT
              MOVE "D"             TO D-ERROR-OUT
              MOVE "**"           TO E-AST-OUT
              MOVE "**"           TO F-AST-OUT
          END-IF
       END-IF.

       MOVE DAY-DUE TO DAY-DUE-NUM.
       MOVE MONTH-DUE TO MONTH-DUE-NUM.

       IF DAY-DUE-NUM > 31 OR DAY-DUE < 0 AND ERROR-FLAG2 = NOO
           MOVE "YES"              TO ERROR-FLAG
           MOVE "**"              TO E-AST-OUT
           MOVE "E"                TO E-ERROR-OUT
       END-IF.

       IF MONTH-DUE-NUM > 12 OR < 1 AND ERROR-FLAG2 = NOO
           MOVE "YES"              TO ERROR-FLAG
           MOVE "**"             TO F-AST-OUT
           MOVE "F"                TO F-ERROR-OUT
       END-IF.

       IF VEND-NAME = SPACES
           MOVE "YES"              TO ERROR-FLAG
           MOVE "***************"               TO G-AST-OUT
           MOVE "G"                TO G-ERROR-OUT
       END-IF.

       IF VEND-NAME(1:1) IS EQUAL TO SPACE
           MOVE "YES"              TO ERROR-FLAG
           MOVE "***************"         TO H-AST-OUT
           MOVE "H"                TO H-ERROR-OUT

       IF AMT-DUE IS NOT NUMERIC
           MOVE "YES"              TO ERROR-FLAG
           MOVE "********"               TO I-AST-OUT
           MOVE "I"               TO I-ERROR-OUT
       END-IF.

       IF ERROR-FLAG = "YES"
            ADD 1 TO INVALID-RECORDS
       END-IF.

       IF ERROR-FLAG = "NO"
           ADD 1 TO VALID-RECORDS
       END-IF.



   2500-PROCESS.
       MOVE RECORD-CODE    TO RECORD-CODE-OUT.
       MOVE VEND-NUM       TO VEND-NUM-OUT.
       MOVE YEAR-DUE       TO YEAR-DUE-OUT.
       MOVE MONTH-DUE      TO MONTH-DUE-OUT.
       MOVE DAY-DUE        TO DAY-DUE-OUT.
       MOVE VEND-NAME      TO VEND-NAME-OUT.
       MOVE AMT-DUE        TO AMT-DUE-OUT.

       WRITE REPORT-RECORD FROM DETAIL-LINE.

   3000-PROCESS.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD FROM ASTERISK-LINE.

   4000-PROCESS.
       MOVE VALID-RECORDS      TO VALID-RECORDS-OUT.
       MOVE INVALID-RECORDS    TO INVALID-RECORDS-OUT.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD     FROM RECORD-TOTALS.

   4200-REINITILIZE.
       MOVE A-ERROR            TO A-ERROR-OUT.
       MOVE B-ERROR            TO B-ERROR-OUT.
       MOVE C-ERROR            TO C-ERROR-OUT.
       MOVE D-ERROR            TO D-ERROR-OUT.
       MOVE E-ERROR            TO E-ERROR-OUT.
       MOVE F-ERROR            TO F-ERROR-OUT.
       MOVE G-ERROR            TO G-ERROR-OUT.
       MOVE H-ERROR            TO H-ERROR-OUT.
       MOVE I-ERROR            TO I-ERROR-OUT.
       MOVE A-AST              TO A-AST-OUT.
       MOVE BC-AST             TO BC-AST-OUT.
       MOVE D-AST              TO D-AST-OUT.
       MOVE E-AST              TO E-AST-OUT.
       MOVE F-AST              TO F-AST-OUT.
       MOVE G-AST              TO G-AST-OUT.
       MOVE H-AST              TO H-AST-OUT.
       MOVE I-AST              TO I-AST-OUT.
       MOVE ERROR-FILLER       TO ERROR-FLAG.
       MOVE ERROR-FILLER       TO ERROR-FLAG2.
       MOVE A-AST              TO DAY-DUE-NUM.
       MOVE A-AST              TO MONTH-DUE-NUM.
   4500-TERMINATE.
       CLOSE DATVAL02, REPORT-FILE.
```

Data in looks as such...

```
VC 10045380051005ABC ELECTRONICS        00001298
VT         000000                       00020000
```

Looking to achieve this

```
XX 9AAA9999  99/99/99       SHIFTED      12A 4GL 78   A   C   E F   H I
** ********     ** **  ***************   *** *** **
```

where * are under errors in the data. And letters show what errors are found.

Comment: All I can tell you is that it happens in the error check, unless you would like a copy of the 22k job spool of the abend

Comment: I asked before looking :-), thinking your program would be more involved than it is. Again you have some other things which could use attention if you are interested.

Comment: Did you check you compile-listing for diagnostics? I can see at least two things. I think enough to break the compile, so the link/bind won't run so the program you are executing is an earlier version, still with the same problem.

Comment: OK, confirmed, you running an old version of your code with the old error in. Updated answer, look for more shortly.

Comment: wait is it running for you?

Comment: No, not running. I just noticed that there is no `END-READ` but you are using `NOT AT END` and `AT END`. I don't use those, so had to check for sure that it gave an eight. There's another thing I was confused by. Can you tell us what version of Enterprise COBOL you are using? It will be on the compile listing. 3.something, 4.something or 5.something.

Comment: Would no end-read make it abend? I'm using IBM rational developer for system Z

Comment: No. Having no END-READ would cause it not to compile cleanly.

Comment: this is completely blowing my mind, are you seeing anything else that could cause it to abend?

Comment: Can you add the WHEN-COMPILED code to you program, and confirm whether or not you see the output? Only numeric fields for can cause a S0C7, and only the source fields for a MOVE. Other than your counts, the only things which are numeric are your date fields (they don't need to be, I'd use PIC XX) and your amount. I've tried counting and the data looks OK. You do have a typo with your printed amount, the V should be a full-stop/period.

Comment: I've now run your program. See the update. I'm 99.999% sure you just haven't been executing the program you thought you were, because of compile errors. Slight possibility of a data error on your file, but I don't see it from the sample data you've posted.

Comment: oh my god... how do i fix it? and you only did those two corrections? you have to understand i've been banging my head against this for 2 straight days. what other things do i need to sort out?

Comment: It's really important to check your compile listings. I've not used Rational Developer. Because your program is not compiling due to the lack of the END-READ, you are running an old version, unchanged, each time, so still getting the original abend. The counts, the END-READ, make the Vendor field PIC X(8) instead of 9(8) and make the printed amount a proper edited field without the V and you should be close.

Comment: Once you have your program running, I suggest you sign up to another StackExchange site, Code Review, which is for working code which you want to know how to improve. SO itself is more for bugged code. You can pick up lots of pointers by reading through a number of the questions and answers here as well.

Comment: can you post the exact code you used to make it run?

Comment: and what compiler are you using?

Comment: Enterprise COBOL V4.1. I only asked because I didn't think you could have a V in an editing PICture. Seems you can, so I've learned something :-) It's late here, so that's the last from me tonight. Good luck.

Comment: Bill, could you please help me here. I still can't figure it out. Could you post your code that you used that made it run on SO, I still can't get even one validation to run and I have no idea why.

Comment: I added an END-READ before the END-PERFORM. That and the two VALUE clauses on the counts were all it needed to compile, run and get output. I had to add the RECORDING MODE as I wanted to use fixed-length files (I used DD *, so LRECL of 80, for input, and SYSOUT for the output, not writing to QSAM datasets). I need to get home now, but I'll look in in 3-4 hours or so. Do you not have anyone working with you who can help? Add the WHEN-COMPILED code I showed and confirm it works, like I asked before, please.

Comment: Any progress with this?

Comment: None, no idea whats the problem. Could you post the exact code that you used to make it run

Comment: OK. At the bottom of the answer. Do you get a compile listing? Does it have any diagnostic messages at the end? Do you get an RC/CC from the compile/link? If you run this, do you get the compile time displayed?

Comment: Bill, i'm about to drive home, but I have now put up my entire code for this program. I would be forever in your debt if you could help me fix it and make it run. I've spent so much time on it and with it ABENDing for me still I'll receive no points for it. It's due at midnight, if not I understand. I truly appreciate how much you have tried to help me.

Comment: OK. I've run your new code and update the answer. Apart from effectively a typo, your program runs, for me, without abend. You can hand your program in knowing it is fairly good for a beginner. You need to sort out how you find things in your "environment". I know you've asked a couple of questions here, but it is your work, and don't be concerned about handing it in (with the little fix for the DUE-DATE thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your latest version, you have made a group item (DATE-DUE) but you have not adjusted the level-numbers for the other date fields which are subordinate to it. I have made those three level 10. To use SYSIN data to be convenient for me, I added a 32-byte FILLER to the end of the input record.

I compile, gets an RC/CC of 4, so the linkedit/binder runs.

I used this data from your other question:

VC 10045380051005ABC ELECTRONICS        00001298
VC         050926XYZ COMPANY            00R00549
VT 12348760051115QUALITY ASSURANCE CO   00400053
VC A14BCF80051201                       00100930

And got this output, with no abend:

```
               VENDOR RECORD VALIDATION                        PAGE 1        
RC VENDOR #  DATE DUE  VENDOR NAME      AMOUNT DUE   -- ERROR CODES--        
VC 10045380  051005  ABC ELECTRONICS       000,012.98                        
VC           050926  XYZ COMPANY           009,005.49     B                  
   ********                                                                  
VT 12348760  051115  QUALITY ASSURANCE CO  004,000.53  A                     
**                                                                           
VC A14BCF80  051201                        001,009.30        C           G  H
   ********            ***************            ********                   
VALID RECORDS:  01  INVALID RECORDS: 03
```

I have pasted the data from your other question.

Note, if your actual data is incorrect, you may get an abend with the amount field.

Note also what has happened to the R in the amount field. You haven't validated that for NUMERIC.

---

I have now compiled and run your program with the two corrections (the VALUE clauses for the two counts, and the END-READ). Here is the output:

```
               VENDOR RECORD VALIDATION                        PAGE 1
RC VENDOR #  DATE DUE  VENDOR NAME      AMOUNT DUE   -- ERROR CODES--
VC 10045380  051005  ABC ELECTRONICS       000,01298                 
VT        0  000000                        000,20000     B           
   ********                                                          
VALID RECORDS:  01  INVALID RECORDS: 01
```

I used a fixed-length file, as I don't have access to your actual file, which must be variable-length (it is good to be explicit in the FD, then you don't get those I-informational messages at the end of your compile).

You still have some things to sort out, but the program is running and producing output. If you make those code changes and still have problems, then it is your file that is in error.

You have a very frustrating problem which seems to be down to the "environment". You need to be able to see your compile listings. If the compile fails (RC/CC above 4) then your linkedit/binder step won't run, and you won't get a new executable program. I think that is your problem, but you need help from your tutor to sort out how to find the compile listing and confirm that there are no errors.

I have not used Rational Developer and don't know if you are using zPDT or are compiling on the Mainframe or how you'd look at the compiler output in either case from your Rational Developer session.

Your code is basically OK for a learner, and probably has been for a couple of days. You have been struggling with a problem not directly to do with the code, but to do with not knowing your program had compile errors. Basically, except for a couple of typos, it was there.

When you do get it running in your environment, update your Code Review question please.

---

A really good thing to know is what compile produced the version of the program that you ran, whether or not it abended.

You can display the date and time that the program was compiled:

```
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  W-WHEN-COMPILED                      PIC X(8)BX(8).
   ...
```

Before doing anything else, other than identifying that it is the first time in a CALLed sub-program, something like this:

```
   MOVE WHEN-COMPILED                TO W-WHEN-COMPILED
   DISPLAY 
           "Program XXXXXXXX compiled on "
           W-WHEN-COMPILED
```

The output you get will be the date/time from the actual compile of that program, matching exactly to the date/time on the compile listing.

I've used code like that, and recommended it to others, for over 30 years, and it has saved shed-loads of time.

There is also an intrinsic FUNCTION, WHEN-COMPILED. This is the same, but with a four-digit year. Since for the forseeable future the CC in the year will be 20 you can chose which one to do. Both are resolved at compile-time, and impact on run-time will be minimal.

---

You have no END-READ. This gives you an E-level diagnostic from the compile, a Return-Code/Condition-Code of 8, and you linkedit/binder step following probably hasn't run (have a look at the COND for the step in file 2 of the spool for your job).

Here is your code as a reminder:

```
 PERFORM UNTIL END-OF-FILE = "YES"
     READ DATVAL02
       AT END
         MOVE "YES" TO END-OF-FILE
       NOT AT END
         PERFORM 2100-ERROR-ROUTINE
         IF ERROR-FLAG = "YES"
            PERFORM 2500-PROCESS
            PERFORM 3000-PROCESS
         END-IF
         IF ERROR-FLAG = "NO"
            PERFORM 2500-PROCESS
         END-IF
   END-PERFORM.
```

Here is what it could look like with the END-READ:

```
 PERFORM UNTIL END-OF-FILE = "YES"
     READ DATVAL02
       AT END
         MOVE "YES" TO END-OF-FILE
       NOT AT END
         PERFORM 2100-ERROR-ROUTINE
         IF ERROR-FLAG = "YES"
            PERFORM 2500-PROCESS
            PERFORM 3000-PROCESS
         END-IF
         IF ERROR-FLAG = "NO"
            PERFORM 2500-PROCESS
         END-IF
       END-READ
   END-PERFORM
```

Since no new program has been linked, you are running the old program still and getting the old error still.

---

You are adding to non-binary fields which you have not given an initial value.

```
   05 VALID-RECORDS     PIC S99.
   05 INVALID-RECORDS   PIC S99.

   IF ERROR-FLAG = "YES"
        ADD 1 TO INVALID-RECORDS
   END-IF.

   IF ERROR-FLAG = "NO"
       ADD 1 TO VALID-RECORDS
   END-IF.
```

Without an initial value (either from a VALUE clause, or a MOVE or even the dread INITIALIZE), the value is undefined and is unlikely to be valid for a zoned-decimal field, so S0C7.

Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17102485/1927206 to see if you can work out from that exactly where it is failing in your program.

---

Program which compiles clean, with RC 0 and no diagnostic messages, and runs without abend:

```
   ID DIVISION.                                                     
   PROGRAM-ID. VARA.                                                
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.


       SELECT DATVAL02 ASSIGN TO DATAIN
          FILE STATUS IS EF-STATUS.

       SELECT REPORT-FILE ASSIGN TO DATAOUT
          FILE STATUS IS PF-STATUS.

   DATA DIVISION.

   FILE SECTION.
   FD DATVAL02 RECORDING MODE F.
   01 SALES-RECORD.
       05 RECORD-CODE   PIC XX.
       05 FILLER        PIC X.
       05 VEND-NUM      PIC X(8).
       05 YEAR-DUE      PIC 99.
       05 MONTH-DUE     PIC 99.
       05 DAY-DUE       PIC 99.
       05 VEND-NAME     PIC X(20).
       05 FILLER        PIC XXX.
       05 AMT-DUE       PIC S9(6)V99.
       05  FILLER PIC X(32).

   FD REPORT-FILE RECORDING MODE F.
   01 REPORT-RECORD                PIC X(80).

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01  W-WHEN-COMPILED             PIC X(8)BX(8).

   01 FLAGS-AND-ACCUMLATORS.
       05 VALID-RECORDS     PIC S99 VALUE ZERO.
       05 INVALID-RECORDS   PIC S99 VALUE ZERO.
       05   EF-STATUS       PIC 99  VALUE 0.
       05   PF-STATUS       PIC 99  VALUE 0.
       05 A-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 C-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 E-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 F-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 B-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 D-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 G-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 H-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 I-ERROR           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 A-AST             PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 BC-AST            PIC X(8) VALUE SPACES.
       05 D-AST             PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 E-AST             PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 F-AST             PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 G-AST             PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.
       05 I-AST             PIC X(8) VALUE SPACES.
       05  END-OF-FILE      PIC XXX VALUE "NO".
       05 ERROR-FLAG        PIC XXX VALUE SPACES.
       05 ERROR-FLAG2       PIC XXX VALUE SPACES.
       05 VC                PIC XX VALUE "VC".
       05 NOO               PIC XX VALUE "NO".
       05 D-CHECK           PIC S9999999V99.


   01 HEADING-LINE-1.
       05           PIC X(15) VALUE SPACES.
       05           PIC X(24) VALUE
            "VENDOR RECORD VALIDATION".
       05           PIC X(24) VALUE SPACES.
       05           PIC X(6)  VALUE
            "PAGE 1".

   01 HEADING-LINE-2.
       05           PIC XX VALUE
            "RC".
       05           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05           PIC X(8) VALUE
            "VENDOR #".
       05           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05           PIC X(8) VALUE
            "DATE DUE".
       05           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05           PIC X(11) VALUE
            "VENDOR NAME".
       05           PIC X(6) VALUE SPACES.
       05           PIC X(10) VALUE
            "AMOUNT DUE".
       05           PIC XXX VALUE SPACES.
       05           PIC X(16) VALUE
            "-- ERROR CODES--".

   01 DETAIL-LINE.
       05 RECORD-CODE-OUT           PIC XX.
       05                           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 VEND-NUM-OUT              PIC 9(8).
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 YEAR-DUE-OUT              PIC XX.
       05 MONTH-DUE-OUT             PIC XX.
       05 DAY-DUE-OUT               PIC XX.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 VEND-NAME-OUT             PIC X(20).
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 AMT-DUE-OUT               PIC 999,999.99.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 A-ERROR-OUT               PIC X.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 B-ERROR-OUT               PIC X.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 C-ERROR-OUT               PIC X.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 D-ERROR-OUT               PIC X.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 E-ERROR-OUT               PIC X.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 F-ERROR-OUT               PIC X.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 G-ERROR-OUT               PIC X.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 H-ERROR-OUT               PIC X.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 I-ERROR-OUT               PIC X.

   01 ASTERISK-LINE.
       05 A-AST-OUT                 PIC XX.
       05                           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 BC-AST-OUT                PIC X(8).
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 D-AST-OUT                 PIC XX.
       05                           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 E-AST-OUT                 PIC XX.
       05                           PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 F-AST-OUT                 PIC XX.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 G-AST-OUT                 PIC X(15).
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 I-AST-OUT                 PIC X(8).
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05 H-AST-OUT                 PIC X(8).

   01 RECORD-TOTALS.
       05                           PIC X(16) VALUE
            "VALID RECORDS: ".
       05 VALID-RECORDS-OUT         PIC 99.
       05                           PIC XX VALUE SPACES.
       05                           PIC X(17) VALUE
            "INVALID RECORDS: ".
       05 INVALID-RECORDS-OUT       PIC 99.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.

   1000-MAIN-CONTROL.
       MOVE WHEN-COMPILED         TO W-WHEN-COMPILED
       DISPLAY
               "TEST PROGRAM COMPILED ON "
               W-WHEN-COMPILED
       PERFORM 2000-INITIALIZE.
       PERFORM UNTIL END-OF-FILE = "YES"
         READ DATVAL02
           AT END
             MOVE "YES" TO END-OF-FILE
           NOT AT END
             PERFORM 2100-ERROR-ROUTINE
             IF ERROR-FLAG = "YES"
                PERFORM 2500-PROCESS
                PERFORM 3000-PROCESS
             END-IF
             IF ERROR-FLAG = "NO"
                PERFORM 2500-PROCESS
             END-IF
         END-READ
       END-PERFORM.
       PERFORM 4000-PROCESS.
       PERFORM 4500-TERMINATE.
       STOP RUN.

   2000-INITIALIZE.
       OPEN INPUT DATVAL02.
       OPEN OUTPUT REPORT-FILE.

       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM HEADING-LINE-1.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD         FROM HEADING-LINE-2.

   2100-ERROR-ROUTINE.
       MOVE "NO"                   TO ERROR-FLAG.
       MOVE "NO"                   TO ERROR-FLAG2.

       IF VEND-NUM = SPACES
           MOVE "YES"              TO ERROR-FLAG
           MOVE "********"         TO BC-AST-OUT
           MOVE "B"                TO B-ERROR-OUT
       END-IF.


       IF ERROR-FLAG = "YES"
            ADD 1 TO INVALID-RECORDS
       END-IF.

       IF ERROR-FLAG = "NO"
           ADD 1 TO VALID-RECORDS
       END-IF.



   2500-PROCESS.
       MOVE RECORD-CODE    TO RECORD-CODE-OUT.
       MOVE VEND-NUM       TO VEND-NUM-OUT.
       MOVE YEAR-DUE       TO YEAR-DUE-OUT.
       MOVE MONTH-DUE      TO MONTH-DUE-OUT.
       MOVE DAY-DUE        TO DAY-DUE-OUT.
       MOVE VEND-NAME      TO VEND-NAME-OUT.
       MOVE AMT-DUE        TO AMT-DUE-OUT.

       WRITE REPORT-RECORD FROM DETAIL-LINE.

   3000-PROCESS.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD FROM ASTERISK-LINE.

   4000-PROCESS.
       MOVE VALID-RECORDS      TO VALID-RECORDS-OUT.
       MOVE INVALID-RECORDS    TO INVALID-RECORDS-OUT.
       WRITE REPORT-RECORD     FROM RECORD-TOTALS.

   4500-TERMINATE.
       CLOSE DATVAL02, REPORT-FILE.
```

Comment: WOW... I can't believe I missed that. I made the change, but it's still abending on me

Comment: I'm still troubled by whats going wrong, it has to be in the few lines of error checking but I just can't figure out what.

Comment: Added the END-READ. I'm fairly sure that's where you want it, but really you should know best :-)